# Is there anything i could do to get rid of this error:

Tags: php, mysql, apache, xampp

"Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Array callback must have exactly two elements ".

error is on line 14:
$name = $_POST ('name');

Answer (score 0):

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
```

Try this not parenthesis.